# Android: onClickListener method does not reach end because it ends first

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I'm having a problem, the following onClickListener

```
 check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Integral prev;
            if(selm.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Trapezi"))
                prev=new Trapezi();
            else
                prev=new SimpsonI();
            txtit.setEnabled(!txtit.isEnabled());
            if(txtit.isEnabled()) {
                calc = calc.getComposite();
            }
            else {
                calc = prev;
            }



        }
    });
```

Does not reach the end of the method, it stops after executing line:

```
txtit.setEnabled(!txtit.isEnabled());
```

This is a very strange issue, so I cannot understand it's reason. I'm very new to android and i'm writing a simple application to become friendly with the Android environment, if my question is stupid, this is why! Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'Does not reach the end of the method'? Does it crash? Did you run with a debugger?

Comment: The lines after are not executed. Everything I write after is ignored by the virtual machine!

Comment: is 'txtit' initialized?

Comment: yes, txtit is initalized before the declaration of this listener

Comment: Please put the log statements after each statement and check which all are printing or batter debug it to see what is getting executed and what it not..

Comment: @AlexFoglia `txtit.isEnabled()` returns true and hence this `txtit.setEnabled(!txtit.isEnabled());` set to false . is your final else statement is getting executed? it must be

Comment: I did it but only the statements that appear before this line are printed on the log

Comment: @Vivek_Neel , in both cases, neither the if nor the else statements are getting executed. If i put a log statement after the last if... else... or everything i want, it is ignored. It's very frustating!

Comment: Please share the code with the log statements and logcat output..

Answer (score 1):

Simply the `if` or `else` statements are valid only to the single line of codes, so add braces in `else` statement like,

```
     Integral prev;
    if(selm.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Trapezi"))
        prev=new Trapezi();
    else
     {
        prev=new SimpsonI();
        txtit.setEnabled(!txtit.isEnabled());
     }
    ...
```

If you want `setEnabled` be executed in each case then even don't mess up the codes reformat it

```
 else
     {
        prev=new SimpsonI();            
     }
    txtit.setEnabled(!txtit.isEnabled());
```

Comment: the if else must decide what kind of Integral must instantiate: Trapezi or SimpsonI, the lines after must be executed independently.

Comment: Then is your final else statement being executed ?

Comment: Can you tell what is `txtit`?

Comment: @AlexFoglia Try moving this line `txtit.setEnabled(!txtit.isEnabled());` before the click handler, like `boolean enabled = txtit.setEnabled(!txtit.isEnabled());` and in the click handler check `if(enabled)`.

Answer (score 1):

You must not have this `txtit.setEnabled(!txtit.isEnabled())` inside your `onClick` .

in your `onCreate` , do :

```
final boolean getValue = txtit.setEnabled(!txtit.isEnabled());
```

and change your `onClick` with mine :

```
check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Integral prev;
            if(selm.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Trapezi"))
                prev=new Trapezi();
            else
                prev=new SimpsonI();

            if(getValue) {
                calc = calc.getComposite();
            }
            else {
                calc = prev;
            }



        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason. Every line I write in every part of the code is ignored because Android Studio does not find the changings. It tells me: no changes to deploy, so it's running a previous version in which are not included latest modifies. So it's not a java-issue but it's an issue related to Android Studio. Thank you all

Comment: Restart the Android Studio by File > Invalidate Caches / Restart.. It will work after that..!!